# Windows and Linux thread priority equivalence

Tags: windows, linux, multithreading

Windows OS defines the following constants as thread priority:

- THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE (-15)
- THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST (-2)
- THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL (-1)
- THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL (0)
- THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL (1)
- THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST (2)
- THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL (15)

And Linux has sched_get_priority_max() and sched_get_priority_min() to get thread priority range.

Is it possible to have an equivalence between Windows and Linux thread priority values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
  sched_get_priority_max(policy);
  sched_get_priority_min(policy);
```

to know the priority range.

Answer (score 4):

Default Linux priority range is between -20 (highest) and 20 (idle) with step of 1 and default of 0. Negative (raised) priorities are assignable only by superuser. Note Linux never claims -20 to be Realtime/Time Critical, and RTLinux uses a separate methods to achieve Realtime. Also note in Linux Kernel space these priorities have a different range. The -20:20 is a strictly userspace thing.